# If the variable $a is equal to 5 and variable $b is equal to character a, what’s the value of $$b?

Tags: php, variables

Answer: 100, it’s a reference to existing variable. 
But I don't understand why the result is 100? who can explain this to me?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Can you supply us with the code in question? Is this what you mean: http://ideone.com/a1yMc ?

Comment: are you sure the answer is 100?

Comment: Please don't ever use variable variables, they're an abomination and ought to be removed from PHP altogether. Your curiosity is understandable, however.

Comment: Show some code demonstrating the problem, because as others have stated in their answers, they get a result of 5

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I get it.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what exactly you're asking, but when I run this code:

```
<?php

$a = 5;
$b = 'a';
echo $$b;
?>
```

I get output of:

```
5
```

Answer (score 2):

This code gives me "5".

```
$a = 5;
$b = "a";
echo ($$b);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have a problem with your code/logic?

```
$a=5;
$b=a;
echo $$b;
```

*Output:* **5**

```
$a=5;
$b='a';
echo $$b;
```

*Output:* **5**

```
$a=5;
$b="a";
echo $$b;
```

*Output:* **5**

$$ is a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) because all of the above are looking for a variable `a` they will all assume `$a` - *unless you have another reference to different variable somewhere in your code which is 100.*

Answer (score 0):

Of course it should be 5 !!

```
$a = 5 ;
$b = 'a' ;

$$b = $( $b ) = $ ( 'a' ) = $a = 5 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If $b was ever declared to be a reference to another variable elsewhere in your code, then varaible variables won't work as expected.

```
<?php 

$a = 5;
$b = 'a';
echo $$b, "\n"; // echoes 5 as expected
$b = &$a;
$b = 'a';
echo $$b, "\n"; // echoes 'a'
```